# I need to join two tables using datatables of codeignitor

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, datatables

I tried

```
$this->datatables
     ->select($this->db->dbprefix('companies').".id as id, company as sname", false)
     ->from("companies")
     ->join("(select finance, name as sname from payment) d", 'd.finance = companies.finance','left')
     ->where("category_id",$parent_id);
```

but the output is showing only names of company, I need to display both company name as well as payment name in name column.

Answer (score 1):

more simple way is "SQL query" instead ORM:

```
$params = array();
$sql =   "select * from companies c 
            left join payment   d 
              on d.finance=c.finance 
           where category_id = ?";

array_push($params, $parent_id);
$result = $this->db->query($sql, $params)->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('companies')
            ->join('payment d', 'd.finance = companies.finance', 'left');
            ->where('category_id', $parent_id);
            ->get();
        
return $query->result();
```